# How can I overload () operator as prefix?

Tags: c++

I want to implement the explicit type conversion between two distance-related classes. I need to overload the `()` as a prefix to use it like:

```
class1=(class2)class2_object;
```

Comment: Search for overloading the cast operator

Comment: So you want to cast a `class2` object to `class2`?

Comment: Perfect example of XY :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at [user-defined conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator).

**Example:**

```
struct Y {};

struct X {
     operator Y() const { return ...; } 
};

int main() {
    X x;
    Y y1 = static_cast<Y>(x); // uses conversion operator
    Y y2 = (Y)x; // also possible, but don't use C-style casts in C++!
    Y y3 = x; // even this is possible...
}
```

With C++11 you can use the keyword `explicit` to avoid accidental implicit casting (i.e. `Y y3 = x;`):

```
     explicit operator Y() const { return ...; }
```

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that the conversion operator will be invoked whenever the compiler wants to convert `X` to `Y`: by `static_cast`, or if you write `Y(someX)`, or even implicitly, if you pass an `X` to a function requiring a `Y`.  (In C++11, you can declare it `explicit`, to avoid the last case.)